Finding Modulation Type and Transmission Power Given Link Requirements
I know that the key to choose the modulation is to find the signal to noise ratio and "cross it" with the given error probability, but I am facing some problems during the calculation of both signal to noise ratio and transmission power.
For receiver power, I cannot find a way to try to find it without making some assumption on transmission power. (eg. using Friis formula for path loss)
Could you please help me to find a solution?


The question is asking you what the transmit power should be-- so you do need to compute the path loss, and determine the SNR needed to transmit 80 Mbps in 20 MHz of BW. (we have to avoid actually doing the homework for you but we can help if you show what you are doing step by step and specifically where you are stuck)

Friis is not required to solve this problem, read my answer

1.- The Link Budget is crucial to any communications system.
While yes, somehow the question looks like a bit of homework, I must say that 1st contact with communications link budgets may be daunting because university professors tend to force calculator-only assessments, while blisfully ignoring tools like
1.1.- the MATLAB Link Budget app
1.2.- Harris link budget
1.3.- AGI STK now Ansys also has tools to quickly build satellite communications link budgets.
AGI guide and this presentation show STK has now built tools for all sorts of link budgets.
The factor n=3 means
ground-ground link.
Increasing path loss exponent of is a pragmatic way, a compromise, close enough to field measurements, to model urban problems that reduce transmitted power along the signal path much faster compared to free space.
As I am showing in the following lines, on 1st contact it's easy to take the wrong turn.
And if the student left on paper and calculator only, each correction iteration means scrapping a lot of paper, yes, a lot of paper, well into XXIth century yet the right-of-passage ritual includes dragging XIXth century paperwork.
So let's get to it :
2.- Path Loss
Either in MATLAB or Excel calculate these start variables, I am copying pasting from Excel :
c   3.00E+08    m/s    # light speed
f   3.00E+09    Hz
d   1.00E+04    m   
PI  3.14159 
n   3   propagation factor          
Dtx 1               
Drx 1               
wavelength  1.00E-01    m           
BW  2.00E+07    Hz  BW[dB]  1.46E+02    dB

Propagation loss, in dB, is
10*n*log(4*PI*d*f/c)    ; Excel
10*n*log10(4*pi*d*f/c)  % MATLAB

The propagation loss with n=3 is
L1  1.83E+02    dB

L1 is NOT free path loss.
Out of field tests mobile operators find out that increasing the free space path loss exponential n from 2 to between 2.5 and 4 or even 6 the models match real data.
From literature reference Wireless Communications, 2nd ed, by T.S.Rappaport
pg139 :

pg141 :

This graph is a bunch field measurements. Real data, no simulations.
If n=2 the model would not match the
acquired data.
(reliable) DATA IS KING
The question reads n=3.
3.- EsN0 to EbN0
People write EsN0 and EbN0 but these two mean
Es/N0 energy per symbol over noise energy per Hz
and
Eb/N0 energy per bit over noise energy per Hz
EsN0(1e-5)[dB]  M   log2M   BER=SER-log2M[dB]   EbN0(1e-5)[dB]
BPSK    9   2   1   0   9
4PAM    13  4   2   3.010299957 9.989700043
QPSK    17  4   2   3.010299957 13.98970004
16QAM   20  16  4   6.020599913 13.97940009
16PSK   24.2    16  4   6.020599913 18.17940009
64QAM   26.5    64  6   7.781512504 18.7184875
32PSK   30  32  5   6.989700043 23.01029996

A binary modularion has same Es and Eb therefore same EsN0 and EbN0.
Increasing bits per (data, not satellite) constellation symbol makes the modulation more efficient from the data point of view but unless increasing transmitted power, for same power, it brings constellation points closer therefore increasing BER (Bit Error Ratio) meaning manking BER worse.
BER means/stands for Bit Error RATIO
not Bit Error rate
BER is the ratio (relation) between received erroenous bits to total amount of sent/received bits.
Rate implies transmission speed, not wrong to total ratio.
To compare different modulations, and as a broadly practice, EbN0 is used, not EsN0.
Now we have all EbN0
4.- EbN0 to SNR
SNR stands for Signal to Noise Ratio.
Digital modulations figure of merit is EbN0.
But to get to S signal power we need 1st to calculate SNR .
EbN0(1e-5)[dB]  SNR[dB]
9   -5.80E+01
9.989700043 -57
13.98970004 -53
13.97940009 -53.01029996
18.17940009 -48.81029996
18.7184875  -48.27121255
23.01029996 -43.97940009

5.- SNR to S
We have noise density measurement N and the signal bandwidth BW
N   -174    dBm/Hz
    -204    dB/Hz
N[dBW]  -5.80E+01   dBW noise

So
SNR[dB] Srx[dBW]    Stx[dBW]    Stx[W]
-5.80E+01   -1.16E+02   1.54E+01    3.44E+01
-57 -114.9794001    16.35795264 43.23099824
-53 -110.9794001    20.35795264 108.5913579
-53.01029996    -110.9897   20.34765268 108.3341221
-48.81029996    -106.7897   24.54765268 284.9477738
-48.27121255    -106.2506126    25.08674009 322.6071654
-43.97940009    -101.9588002    29.37855255 866.6729767

6.-
The choice of modulation and answer would be the lowest S : BPSK .
7.- Additional Comments
7.1.- The formula that relates SNR to EbN0 , data rate rb , and signal bandwidth BW is
SNR[dB]=EbN0[dB]+rb[dB]-BW[dB]      
        
rb  8.00E+07    bps
rb[dB]  7.90E+01    

7.2.- Antenna diversity MIMO
Multiple Input Multiple Output
and OFDM
Orthogonal Frequency Digital Modulation
may signficantly improve, meaning reduce, power requirements, perhaps by 1 order of magnitude, just using OFDM and multiple tx rx antennas.
7.3.- Dtx and Drx are both set to 1, both omnidirectional.
Because the problem did not mention either, then 1 for both is reasonable.
With modest directivity at reception Drx=1/3 and with 120° sector on transmitter Dtx=1/3 another 10dB gained, on top of using MIMO and OFDM.
7.4.- To refresh link budget basics read here.
7.5.- To refresh path loss basics read here.
Happy to help. Be of service.

Nice summary John--I think you meant for d to be1e4 and for the path loss formula to be 10log10(4pidf/c)^n? This would make the free space path loss (n=2) be 20*og10(4pi d f/c) = 122 dB and with exponent n=3 (large scale fading) it's then 30log10(4pi d f/c) =183 dB.   I didn't read to the end yet but that jumped out when I started and wanted to check if I was missing something --Do you agree?

Dan thanks so much for pointing my 30dB error ! I gave corrected the spreadsheet. It's BPSK.

Nice - but you didn’t update your path loss in the post - you still don’t have the exponent in the formula and your stated PL for n=3 is 41.3 dB. Am I misreading it?

L1 is now 131dB thanks again Dan
